# Rshiny modal popup when good tab selected with navbarPage function

Tags: r, shiny, module, tabs, modal-dialog

I have a modular Rshiny application in which I want to display a dataset selection popup (modal) ONLY when the user is on the "TAB 1" tab.
Ideally, I would like this popup to be displayed only once on the first click on the right tab.

I really don't know how to get the input on which tab is active and then, create a counter to display popup only if counter == 1....

Here is my code :

1st module :

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
#_________________________________________________________________
#                          MODULE 1                           ----
#_________________________________________________________________

module1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(
    title = "Home",
    shiny::tags$p(
      "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."
    )
  )
  
}

module1_server <- function(id, r_global) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    
  })
}
```

2nd module :

```
#_________________________________________________________________
#                          MODULE 2                           ----
#_________________________________________________________________
module2_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(
    title = "Tab 1",
    
    useShinyjs(),
    
    actionLink(
      inputId = ns("display_modal"),
      label = "S\u00e9lectionner les donn\u00e9es",
      style = "position: relative; left:90%"
    ),
    
    tableOutput(outputId = ns("myTable"))
  )
}

module2_server <- function(id, r_global) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    #_________________________________________________________________
    #                      MODAL DEFINITION                       ----
    #_________________________________________________________________
    dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
      modalDialog(
        shiny::tags$h3("Choose dataset : "),
        
        panel(
          shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
            inputId = ns("dataset_select"),
            label = "Dataset :",
            choices = c("dt1" = "dt1",
                        "dt2" = "dt2"),
            multiple = FALSE,
            options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
          )
        ),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton(label = "Cancel"),
          actionButton(inputId = ns("ok"), label = "OK")
        )
      )
    }
        
    #_________________________________________________________________
    #                          SHOW MODAL                         ----
    #_________________________________________________________________
    showModal(dataModal())
    
    #_________________________________________________________________
    #              ACTION WHEN CLICKING ON OK MODAL               ----
    #_________________________________________________________________
    observeEvent(input$ok, {
      removeModal()
      
      output$myTable = renderTable({
        if(input$dataset_select == "dt1"){
          iris
        }else{
          mtcars
        }
      })
    })
    
    #________________________________________________________________
    #        ACTION WHEN CLICKING ON LINK TO DISPLAY MODAL       ----
    #________________________________________________________________
    observeEvent(input$display_modal, {
      showModal(dataModal())
    })
  })
}
```

UI et SERVER:

```
#________________________________________________________________
#                          MAIN UI                           ----
#________________________________________________________________
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(
    navbarPage(id = "main_menu", "My app", 
               module1_ui("mod1"),
               module2_ui("mod2")
    )
  )
}

#________________________________________________________________
#                        MAIN SERVER                         ----
#________________________________________________________________
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  r_global <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  module1_server(id = "mod1", r_global = r_global)
  module2_server(id = "mod2", r_global = r_global)
}

shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server)
```

Comment: Where is the `panel` function from?

Comment: I forgot to mention these libraries : 

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)

```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use a `reactive` in the main server to store the selected tab and pass it to the module 2 server via an additional argument. Inside the module 2 server you could use an `observeEvent` and check that you are on `Tab 1`. Additionally I implemented a `counter` as a `reactiveVal` such that the modal pops up only when listing `Tab 1` the first time.

Code below includes only the module 2 server and the main server:

```
module2_server <- function(id, r_global, tab) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns

    counter <- reactiveVal(1)
    
    # _________________________________________________________________
    #                      MODAL DEFINITION                       ----
    # _________________________________________________________________
    dataModal <- function(failed = FALSE) {
      modalDialog(
        shiny::tags$h3("Choose dataset : "),
        panel(
          shinyWidgets::pickerInput(
            inputId = ns("dataset_select"),
            label = "Dataset :",
            choices = c(
              "dt1" = "dt1",
              "dt2" = "dt2"
            ),
            multiple = FALSE,
            options = list(`actions-box` = TRUE)
          )
        ),
        footer = tagList(
          modalButton(label = "Cancel"),
          actionButton(inputId = ns("ok"), label = "OK")
        )
      )
    }

    # _________________________________________________________________
    #                          SHOW MODAL                         ----
    # _________________________________________________________________
    observeEvent(tab(), {
      if (tab() == "Tab 1") {
        if (counter() == 1) {
          showModal(dataModal())
        }
        counter(counter() + 1)
      }
    })

    # _________________________________________________________________
    #              ACTION WHEN CLICKING ON OK MODAL               ----
    # _________________________________________________________________
    observeEvent(input$ok, {
      removeModal()
     
      output$myTable <- renderTable({
        if (input$dataset_select == "dt1") {
          iris
        } else {
          mtcars
        }
      })
    })

    # ________________________________________________________________
    #        ACTION WHEN CLICKING ON LINK TO DISPLAY MODAL       ----
    # ________________________________________________________________
    observeEvent(input$display_modal, {
      showModal(dataModal())
    })
  })
}

app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  r_global <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)

  selected_tab <- reactive({
    input$main_menu
  })
  
  module1_server(id = "mod1", r_global = r_global)
  module2_server(id = "mod2", r_global = r_global, tab = selected_tab)
}
```